# How do I prevent the user from changing the set TextEditingController text?

Tags: flutter

I've set up a TextEditingController in my code and I want to find a way to stop the user from changing the given text already inputted into the widget by my code.

I've created a TextEditingController() and set the text to what I want (which I don't want the user to change, but to add on after).

_controller = new TextEditingController();

_controller.text = "Example: ";

I can still backspace the text after setting it as above, so is there away to ensure the user cannot backspace the controllers text?

Comment: use Text instead of TextField or set TextField disabled

Answer (score 1):

Try this code let me know if I understand you correctly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(InitialSetupPage());

class InitialSetupPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "EditText manuplation",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  static TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: "Initial:")
  ..addListener((){
    if(! _controller?.text?.startsWith("Initial:")){
      _controller?.value = _controller?.value?.copyWith(text: "Initial:") ;

    }
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body:  Container(
        child: TextField(controller: _controller,)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is basically it, just that I don't want the cursor of the user to go before the preset text if that makes sense, similar to having a prefix in the textfield, but I want to be able to center the prefix, which I can't do in the default version of the widget.

Comment: what exactly you mean by center the prefix , can you explain more

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can do something like this. This one will restore your text if you use something like backspace or cut.

```
TextField(
  controller: textEditingController,
  onChanged: (text){
    if(text.length < textEditingController.text.length){
      textEditingController.text = textEditingController.text;
    }
  },
),
```